# Is there any free membership extension for magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, extensions

My magento site will have membership,where user will by a contract for like 1 year or 6 months,and after that they have to renew every 6 months or 1 year.

Answer (score 4):

Magento offers recurring profiles. You can read more about that [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles).
This will require the client to pay regular invoices.

To automate the process of having a member you can probably write an extension that uses a cronjob to check if the invoice was payed, if not inactivate the customer. Otherwise you'll have to check manually.

Comment: Or maybe just put them in a customer group and use this extension: https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, funny enough that's what I did a few years back and it works great!